# Is this SQL statement for getting annual sales (revenues) correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CUSTOMER (idCustomer,name,phone,email, markdown)
ORDER (idOrder,day,Customer_idCustomer)
ORDERITEM (idOrderItem, quantity, Order_idOrder, Product_idProduct)
PRODUCT (idProduct,name,price,description)
```

Is this statement correct? It seems to me it's getting me right result but I want to verify it. Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT SUM((oi.quantity * p.price) * c.markdown)
FROM orderitem oi,
     product p,
     customer c,
     `order` o 
WHERE oi.Product_idProduct = p.idProduct    
  AND o.Customer_idCustomer = c.idCustomer
  AND (o.day BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
```

EDIT: With JOIN (and every table joined):

```
SELECT SUM((oi.quantity * p.price) * c.markdown) FROM orderitem oi
JOIN product p ON oi.Product_idProduct = p.idProduct 
JOIN `order` o ON o.idOrder = oi.Order_idOrder 
JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = o.Customer_idCustomer 
AND (o.day BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
```

EDIT #2: Ok. So I took my data to Excel and made calculations here to verify the results and it seems that statement with JOIN is correct. Thank zou everyone!

Comment: It would be nice to see a JOIN in that query

Comment: If you want to verify it test it.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Correct as far as what? Syntax? Format? Calculations? Nothing is joining Order Item to Order. So, my guess would be you won't get the right answer you want.

Comment: It does not calculate anything useful, as far as I can tell.  You should be able to see that by running it on your data.

Comment: Why invoke customer it's not used?

Comment: Ok. I used JOIN and joined everything but now it's giving me really weird result (number is definitely too low). 

     `SELECT SUM((oi.quantity * p.price) * c.markdown) FROM orderitem oi JOIN product p ON oi.Product_idProduct = p.idProduct JOIN `order` `o ON o.idOrder = oi.Order_idOrder JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = o.Customer_idCustomer AND (o.day BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')`

Answer (score 0):

This should be probably the right solution:

```
SELECT SUM((oi.quantity * p.price) * c.markdown) FROM orderitem oi
JOIN product p ON oi.Product_idProduct = p.idProduct 
JOIN `order` o ON o.idOrder = oi.Order_idOrder 
JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = o.Customer_idCustomer 
AND (o.day BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
```